# Cant adjust the volume using F10/F11 while bluetooth headset is connected

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

So I have a Sennheiser Momentum M2 AEBT headphone. I connect it to my M1 pro Macbook Pro on MacOS 12.4 and volume control doesnt work using the buttons on the keyboard. I can adjust the volume using the slider on settings or the slider on the control panel but when I try to change it with the buttons, it seems like volume level is 3 and half bars and cant increase or decrease it. (If I hold pressing when a media is not playing sometimes volume changes a little, but always one of the bars is half filled)

Steps I have taken to solve the problem

- Restart the Mac
- Factory reset the Mac
- Forget the bluetooth device from Mac
- Clear paired devices on headphone

Note: Everything is working when the headphone is connected to an iphone or a windows pc.

Comment: Did you check [there](https://www.howtoisolve.com/fix-mac-volume-buttons-not-working/) ?

Comment: I have the same issue. No help from Apple. I had a new machine; same thing. It could be the M1 chip itself.